# designing a view that make icons fill screen but not stretch the images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I currently have the following layout (see below). Now the issue I am having with it, is that i need the icons to fill up the screen (So i need to split the screen into 6 blocks.  But the biggest problem is my images are stretching and that looks really bad. all the images are 256X256.  What can I do to rather have more while space above or below than have them stretched?

Layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.60"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/category_menu_button_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_icon"
            android:contentDescription="Food Menu"
            android:onClick="foodMenuItemClicked"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_menu_label_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:ems="20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:textSize="25sp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon"
            android:contentDescription="Drinks Menu"
            android:onClick="searchMenuItemClicked"
            android:paddingTop="55dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_menu_label_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:ems="20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textSize="25sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cart_icon"
            android:contentDescription="Favorites"
            android:onClick="favoritesMenuItemClicked"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_menu_label_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:ems="20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cart"
            android:textSize="25sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.60"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bill_icon"
            android:contentDescription="View Bill"
            android:onClick="billMenuItemClicked"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_menu_label_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:ems="20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bill"
            android:textSize="25sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/activity_category_menu_button_callWaiter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/callwaiter_icon"
            android:contentDescription="Call Waiter"
            android:onClick="callWaiterButtonClicked"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_menu_label_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:ems="20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Call Waiter"
            android:textSize="25sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/exit_icon"
            android:contentDescription="Exit App"
            android:onClick="exitButtonClicked"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_menu_label_food"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:ems="20"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Exit App"
            android:textSize="25sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Change the scaleType.  You probably want fitCenter.

Comment: Ok I have tried the selected. Now the Icons are small and there is allot of space. Is there a way i can now enlarge them. but without disturbing the aspect ratio?

Comment: Yes, you could read the documentation for `scaleType` which explains each possible value or do what I do, try the different values to see what effect they have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can to use `wrap_content` for **layout_width and layout_height** of `ImageView`

**and**

you use `RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout`.

you use **RelativeLayout** in `Root of layout` and **two ReltavieLayout in sub of Root**. and for not stretch your image, you should to use different size image for different size and density device.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the width and height of images , Leave the height/width attribute to **WRAP_CONTENT** in this way images will neither shrink nor stretch.

Answer (score 0):

please try to change the width and height to wrap content instead of giving match parent.
or else change the scaletype to fitxy.